# How do I switch DataTemplate by RadioButton checked state changing using only xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have WPF window which contains Frame and two RadioButtons. I need to switch Frame's ContentTemplate by changing RadioButtons checked state. How do I implement that using only xaml?

Comment: every guy which follow "only xaml" idioms is looking for adventure on its ass. take it easy, and people will follow you!

Comment: Use Event Triggers in WPF.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353786/condition-in-an-eventtrigger

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to say that my Frame and RadioButtons placed in DataTemlate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't much to go on since you didn't add any sample code.. Try something like this

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate1">
                    <TextBlock Text="Template 1"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate2">
                    <TextBlock Text="Template 2"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <StackPanel>
                <Frame x:Name="frame1"
                        Height="100"
                        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate1}"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="template1RadioButton" IsChecked="True" Content="Template 1"/>
                <RadioButton x:Name="template2RadioButton" Content="Template 2"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=template2RadioButton, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="frame1" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource dataTemplate2}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Triggers` of `Radio Button` like

```
 <RadioButton.Triggers>
  <Trigger Property="RadioButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
           //enter your xaml  here..     
  </Trigger>
 </RadioButton.Triggers>
```

You can see more information about Triggers on this blog [Triggers](http://soumya.wordpress.com/2009/10/18/wpf-simplified-part-2-triggers/)

Comment: `RadionButton.Triggers` only supports EventTriggers

Comment: That code throw exception. Triggers collection need EventTrigger items.